# How can I use multiprocessing without initializing the entire application every time?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I implemented an app which initially creates a connection/channel to rabbitmq and starts a consumer. On an incoming message the consumer executes a function which runs it´s tasks via multiprocessing. I also tried multitasking, but in this case multiprocessing has the better performance by far.

My question is, since on every task a new interpreter process gets started, the entire initialization will be done with every new process. How can i avoid this? Is there any architectural pattern or multiprocessing functionality?

Thank you!

Comment: Initialization should only occur in the `if __name__  == "__main__"` block, anything that occurs outside of that will occur in every subprocess. You could also use `fork` instead of `spawn`, but you sohuld be designing your programming in the way I mentioned anyway

Comment: For questions like these *always* add the operating system you're running Python on to the tags. There are *significant differences* between how different operating systems implement `multiprocessing`.

Comment: See the "Safe importing of main module" subsection of [The spawn and forkserver start methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#the-spawn-and-forkserver-start-methods) section of the multiprocessing [Programming guidelines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#programming-guidelines) in the documentation.